# Matomo Disable int Siteid

Tags: matomo

Ive setup matomo onprem for purpose of tracking user interaction from mobile apps and websites. The setup works fine with siteid as int.

Is there a way to disable int SiteID in matomo?

I've tried using this plugin
https://github.com/joubertredrat/Matomo-ProtectTrackID and currently hashed siteid works and so does int siteid.

The need to disable the incremental site id is mainly to prevent any one to be able to push data where i don't want them to.